# Caliburn Micro bind property to method with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I use Caliburn.Micro in my application.
I have this ListBox

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static models:Tags.AvailableTags}}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding ???}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Basically, I want to bind the IsChecked Property of the CheckBox to a method of the DataContext. How would I go about that? I know how to bind events in Caliburn.Micro, but I never bound a method to a property. The method also has a property.

Comment: My brain is about to blow up))) You can't bind a property to a method. What are you trying to achieve, more precisely?)))

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the ListBox collection in your view to a BindableCollection having the properties you wish to display, i.e. Name and Enabled.

```
public class MyCollection
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Then in you view model bind to the collection of MyCollection objects:

```
public class YourViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _Aggregator;
    private BindableCollection<MyCollection> tags= new BindableCollection<MyCollection>();

    public YourViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator)
    {
        if (aggregator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregator");
        _Aggregator = aggregator;
        _Aggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public BindableCollection<MyCollection> AvailableTags
    {
        get
        {
            if (tags== null)
                tags= new BindableCollection<MyCollection>();

            return tags;
        }
        set
        {
            tags= value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyCollection);
        }
    }  
}
```

Since you're also using a standard WPF ListBox, Caliburn allows you to bind to the collection to your view based on convention:`<ListBox x:Name=AvailableTags />`